# If my script is marked DontDestroyOnLoad, will the values saved in the script keep persistent through scene change?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had a question in regard to DontDestroyOnLoad game objects.

For example, if on scene 0, I set the value of something in the DontDestroyOnLoad script to 1, when the original, startup value was 5. Then, if I go to scene 1, will the value save as 1? or will it revert back to 5?

Comment: It will stay thru the scene change on your last set value, which is 1 until you stop the playmode. You could probably just tried it and got a quicker answer.

Comment: Isn't this something you could easily test yourself? But yes it will stay since your object+ component is not destroyed so why should it be reset?

Answer (score 0):

It should remain as 1 according to your example.